# Connecting GNS3 to Internet.. curious about the IP

Tags: router

BTW!! I am able to connect to the internet via GNS3 Router.  My question is about the IP Address that's assigned to the router!

Here it goes:

So this is my set up in GNS3:

Router 1 --->  Cloud (using my local MS loopback interface)

I had been struggling to get my router to the internet for a while. I'd run ipconfig and found that my wireless connection had an IP of 10.x.x.x with a gateway of .1. So obviously, I was trying to manually assign my MS loopback a random address of like 10.x.x.25 (/24, so still within the same subnet).  But it never worked!!

Finally gave up, and then a new idea hit me.  I set my MS loopback as "receive IP via DHCP", and also my GNS3 router interface that's facing the loopback cloud as "receive IP via DHCP".

They both received an IP Address of 192.168.x.x, and it connected to the internet as well. Duh.. no wonder my manual 10.x.x.x didn't work.

I did an ipconfig/all.... I just could not see a 192.168.x.x subnet in there at all.. no trace of it, just 10.x.x.x was present.

Where DID this 192.168.x.x IP come from?  Difference between 10.x and the 192.x address?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I figured it out. 10.x would be an IP address if it was handed out by my home router.

Here, since I allowed my Loopback to link up with my real router, my PC is behaving as a DHCP server instead, on behalf of my real home router. So 192.168.x is a pool belonging to my PC which handed out an IP to my virtual GNS3 router.

A traceroute to a google dns server revealed the works behind the scenes. It reach the 192.168.x.1 and THEN went to the 10.x.x.1. So my PC is like a proxy right?